# How to create new keyboard shortcuts for change case options in Mac illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to set key commands where Illustrator CC doesn't have any, specifically for Change Case > UPPERCASE, lowercase, Title Case, Sentence case. I have done this for InDesign CC and want to create/use the same key commands in Illustrator.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done the same way you did it in InDesign.

1. Select Keyboard Shortcuts from the Edit Menu

[image: Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts]

2. With Menu Commands Selected in the Drop Down menu, navigate to Change Case under the Type Menu

[image: Menu Commands]

3. Select the command you'd like to create the shortcut for, click on the box under Shortcut and type the keyboard shortcut you'd like to use.

[image: enter the Command]

4. Save your new shortcut set at the top of the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Drop down your Edit menu and select "Keyboard Shortcuts...". Change the selection from Tools to Menu Commands. Expand the Type option. Drop down the Change Case option and start setting your short cuts.

Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts > Menu Commands > Type > Change Case